Admin: "Add New Entry" Slide Out Fails - Cannot create new entry
Craft 4.9.2: Slide out creates draft when fields are completed. "Create Entry" results in toast that indicates a server error. No visible error in the logs but console error is:
GET https://starter.local/admin/?v=1715188470475 403 (Forbidden) axios.js?v=1715188058:2
This is observable in all environments. Screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ltrs77tvj37ui2bqfg0hj/axios-forbidden-error.png
Any ideas?
